# Jmeter Windows authentication parameterization from Http Authorization manager

Tags: jmeter

How can I parameterize the username and password from HTTP Authorization manager?

I tried to parameterize the username from HTTP Authorization manager, and it's not taking the new parameters from the CSV file.

I checked the response, and it always takes 1st parameter.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your JMeter setup is not correct in terms of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

Try placing your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to be **children** of the HTTP Request Sampler you would like to parameterise.

[image: JMeter Auth Manager CSV Data Set Config Scoping Rules]

Also make sure there are no recorded hard-coded values somewhere in [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as it might override the value, generated by the HTTP Authorization Manager

Comment: Verified Jmeter setup is correct as per scope rules.i saw the response hard coding to one user , if i login to application manually correct user is displayed. i added debug post processor and saw the paremeter usernames for each iteration but those are not displayed in response, not sure how to solve the issue?

Comment: @Hi Dmitri, i tried this solution again, jmeter always takes windows credentials, it is not taking the credentials from CSV file for parameterization, any thoughts on this?